# How can I print each line from a Reader

Tags: java, inputstream, writer

so i am working on a project where I am making an SMTP server. I am trying to read in each line of input and then hand that line to another thread for processing. However, with this code, the lines aren't sent until the connection is ended. I think it has to do with the fact that a new line doesn't break the while loop:

```
while (true) {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1){ //this reads the line
                line.append((char) c); //add the character to our line
            }
            String response = Parser.parse(line.toString); //give the line we just read to the parser for processing
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("IOException while reading the clients mesasge");
        }
}
```

I am also going to quote "Java Network Programming 4th edition" by Elliot Harold because the author says that we shouldn't use the readLine() method of a BufferedReader or a DataInputStream because different operating systems have different newline delimeters (\n or \r\n or something else)

Also, I'm not using either of those streams so even if i wanted to use the readLine() I wouldn't be able to do.

Anyone have any idea how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1){ //this reads the line
```

No it doesn't. It reads one character.

Use `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

> I am also going to quote "Java Network Programming 4th edition" by Elliot Harold because the author says that we shouldn't use the readLine() method of a BufferedReader or a DataInputStream because different operating systems have different newline delimeters (\n or \r\n or something else).

Elliot Rusty Harold needs to read the Javadoc, and so do you. This is grade A BS. See the reviews at Amazon for a long list of mistakes in this book.

Comment: well it actually reads more than one character, it currently reads until an EOF. I am trying to read the whole line but as stated above, the author claims that readLine() should not be used because different operating systems have different newline characters.

Comment: @yasgur99 It reads one character at a time until EOF. Nothing to do with lines whatsoever. Your author is mistaken and needs to read the Javadoc.

Comment: @yasgur99 See the Javadoc yourself.

Comment: For a book without that error see my *Fundamental Networking in Java,* Springer 2005.

Comment: thank you so much I really appreciate it. you can see how i was confused because i was like if you can't use readLine() what else can you do!

Comment: It baffles me how that mistake ever got made in the first place, given what it says in the Javadoc, let alone how it has persisted into four editions.